# I cannot recognize what type of formatting element it is in this Word document and how to get rid of it

Tags: microsoft-word, formatting, openoffice

I have got a big Word document that contains what I believe are input forms. How on earth can I delete them without deleting the table cells and what kind of formatting is this? [image] And this is not the Word fields.

A sample 30 kb page of this document is on OneDrive [docx file](https://1drv.ms/w/s!AjdsXoty9xN2gWKasNnDgiD-8gm4?e=vmEnhr)

Would appreciate if anybody helps.

Comment: Looks  like bookmarks. Check if the document has bookmarks (or hidden bookmaks).

Comment: I added an OpenOffice tag to your question. If you feel this is incorrect, please delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The square brackets represent bookmarks. Your document has an hidden bookmark.
Opening it with LibreOffice Writer, then Insert -> Bookmark shows that there are more than one bookmarks (see first screenshot). Pressing Ctrl+A to select them all then clicking on Delete, remove them all.

On MS Word, Insert -> Bookmark. Select Hidden bookmarks to display the bookmark on the list. However, it only shows a single hidden bookmark (see second screenshot).

[image: Bookmark window - LibreOffice Writer]

[image: Bookmark window - MS Word]

Comment: Oh, that was a great help from you, appreciate it so much! I managed to delete this in the LibreOffice Writer "Insert Bookmark dialog". Thanks so much))

Answer (score 1):

I started telling you they are bookmarks Then I checked your file and they are not bookmarks. They do not print. They are not Content Controls.

Unless you have some code that fills out your form, you can certainly delete them. Place your cursor after them, in the same cell, and backspace.

Was this form imported from another file type or program?

Comment: Unfortunately, the ones in the right columns cannot be deleted..

Comment: Given the accepted answer, my guess is that this file originated in Office Libre. Word does not see these as bookmarks and as far as I can tell they serve no purpose and do not really hurt anything. The characters look like bookmarks, as I originally said, but they are not Word bookmarks.

Comment: To get rid of them, open it in Office Libre (Open Office) and delete them in the bookmarks dialog.

Comment: .. and they were printed also that's why it got on my nerves )

Comment: Yes, deleted at last in LibreOffice Writer!

Comment: Even though LibreOffice is a compatible program, it does not follow the same file protocols. (This may be because Microsoft does not share everything.)